# How to make a twitter moment directly from a list ot tweets?

Tags: twitter

Does anyone know if there is a service or something that would turn a list of tweet html links automatically into twitter moment? For instance, I have the links of 5 tweets and I want to turn them into a twitter moment automatically without having to add them one by one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Twitter don't provide an API for a "moment" but they do offer something similar. A "collection".

Using the [collections API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/curate-a-collection/overview/about_collections) you can add a bunch of Tweets to a collection and then share it.

Without knowing what code you've already written, it's hard to give more precise advice. But I hope that link will be enough to get you started.